# How to delete a matching block once a pattern is matched

Tags: xml, shell, sed, xmlstarlet

Here is the file (named it as sample.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configs>

    <blah1 value="ma">
      <tag3>100MB</tag3>
    </blah1>

    <blah1 value="ba">
      <tag3>20MB</tag3>
    </blah1>

     <blah2 value="*" version="1.0" result="true">
        <blah1 value="xyz">
          <blah1 value="uvw" result="true">
             <tag>4</tag>
          </blah1>
        </blah1>
     </blah2>

  <!-- This is tag with def value -->
  <blah2 value="*" version="2.0" result="true">
    <blah1 value="abc">
      <blah1 value="def" result="true">
        <tag2>on</tag2>
      </blah1>
    </blah1>
  </blah2>

</configs>
```

On finding a string with `value="def"`, remove the entire block beginning from `<blah2> to </blah2>` tags

Am not familiar with `sed` hold pattern but something I got from google which is very close

```
sed -n '/<blah2.*>/,/<\/blah2>/{
                                  H
                                  /<\/blah2>/ { 
                                        s/.*//;x
                                       /def/d
                                       p 
                                  }
                               }' sample.xml
```

Expected result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configs>

    <blah1 value="ma">
      <tag3>100MB</tag3>
    </blah1>

    <blah1 value="ba">
      <tag3>20MB</tag3>
    </blah1>

     <blah2 value="*" version="1.0" result="true">
        <blah1 value="xyz">
          <blah1 value="uvw" result="true">
             <tag>4</tag>
          </blah1>
        </blah1>
     </blah2>

</configs>
```

Actual result (with above non-working sed):

```
     <blah2 value="*" version="1.0" result="true">
        <blah1 value="xyz">
          <blah1 value="uvw" result="true">
             <tag>4</tag>
          </blah1>
        </blah1>
     </blah2>
```

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Is `def` always an attribute of tag `/configs/blah2[2]/blah1/blah1`?

Comment: Right, currently xmlstarlet is not available on that host(which is some proprietary linux) and no internet access. I will have to download and move the binary there.

Comment: Yes, def is always attribute in second blah1

Comment: Would an answer with xmlstarlet help you?

Comment: I would like to know the normal sed answer and then xmlstarlet answer is bonus. BTW, to make it simple you can assume def can be either of the inside blah1 tags. Can we make the hold space and pattern space work for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<blah2.*>/{:a;N;/<\/blah2.*>/!ba;/value="def"/d}' file
```

If a line contains `<blah2.*>` gather up all lines until a line containing `<\/blah2.*>`, then test those lines for the string `value="def"` and if found, delete those lines.

Comment: One problem is we cannot make use of previous tag section values like "ma" and "ba".. They may or may not be present

Comment: @satya: `b` is a `sed` command. `:a` is a label with name `a`. `/<\/blah2.*>/!ba`: If `<\/blah2.*>` was not found in pattern space then jump to label `a`. This is a loop until `<\/blah2.*>` is found.

Comment: oh! my bad. Let me try this

Comment: This works great! One last thing that I forgot to mention that, sometimes there is comment above the tag section. Can that be removed as part of sed? If not I can delete it separately as another sed.

Comment: If the comment line is the line before the `<blah2.*>` line use: `sed 'N;/<blah2.*>/{:a;N;/<\/blah2.*>/!ba;/value="def"/d};P;D' file`

Answer (score 3):

Delete second tag `blah2` with xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --delete '//configs[blah2[2]/blah1/blah1[@value="def"]]/blah2[2]' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configs>
  <blah1 value="ma">
    <tag3>100MB</tag3>
  </blah1>
  <blah1 value="ba">
    <tag3>20MB</tag3>
  </blah1>
  <blah2 value="*" version="1.0" result="true">
    <blah1 value="xyz">
      <blah1 value="uvw" result="true">
        <tag>4</tag>
      </blah1>
    </blah1>
  </blah2>
</configs>
```

If you want to edit file inplace, add option -L.

---

Explanation of the used [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
//configs[blah2[2]/blah1/blah1[@value="def"]]/blah2[2]
|---A---| |-------------B------------------| |---C---|
```

> A and B: path to the attribute you are looking for
>
> A and C: path to the tag to be deleted

Comment: but this one doesn't check for tag with value "def". The number of tag sections can be more or less.

Comment: Great! one question. can xml comment above this tag section be deleted using xmlstarlet?

Comment: Add `--delete '//configs/comment()'` to `xmlstarlet edit` command to delete all commands in tag `configs`.

Comment: Thank you @cyrus. I am just choosing the sed answer as accepted solution because of the current restrictions I have. Ideally I would like to choose both answers as accepted answers

Comment: @satya - Here's another (untested) xpath option: `//blah2[.//blah1/@value='def']`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're happy with a sed solution, here's a better (clearer, more portable, etc.) alternative given your posted sample input/output:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/value="def"/' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configs>

    <blah1 value="ma">
      <tag3>100MB</tag3>
    </blah1>

    <blah1 value="ba">
      <tag3>20MB</tag3>
    </blah1>

     <blah2 value="*" version="1.0" result="true">
        <blah1 value="xyz">
          <blah1 value="uvw" result="true">
             <tag>4</tag>
          </blah1>
        </blah1>
     </blah2>

</configs>
```

If that's not all you need, there's a better awk alternative for whatever it is you do need since sed is only best for doing s/old/new on individual strings.

Comment: is it possible to remove comment line(s) along with the block. The comment can be single line before or a multi line one 
```xml
<!-- This is tag with def value -->

or 

<!-- This is a multi line
tag for demo purpose -->
```

Comment: Look at the output I posted - it did remove the comment line (see how `<!-- This is tag with def value -->` is not present in the output?) and it doesn't matter if it's single or multiple lines

Comment: Ok Right, I tried and it works if they are separated by newline. If I remove newline between blah2 blocks or if I remove new line between last blah2 block and the configs, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @satya all we have to go on is the sample input you provide. If your real input doesn't follow the same format as your sample input then you shouldn't expect any solution that doesn't use an XML parser to work robustly. If you can use an XML parser then you should. If you can't then update your example to truly reflect your files format and you may be able to get a sed or awk answer to handle that specific format.